# How to find and select a table in html code with xpath

Tags: xpath, python-2.7, lxml

I am new in python and xpath, 
I have a html code like this:

```
<a name="hello"></a>
<h3>hello</h3>
<table />

<a name="impact"></a>
<h3>Impact</h3>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="wrapper-table"><tr> <td><p>An     unauthenticated attacker using a specifically crafted payload may be able to trick the Ruby on Rails backend into executing arbitrary code.</p></td></tr></table>
```

and I want to save the whole table with all its tags and text and... in a string.
I want the table tag that is after the impact header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
tables = root.xpath('.//table[preceding-sibling::h3[text()="Impact"]]')
```

or

```
tables = root.xpath('.//h3[text()="Impact"]/following-sibling::table')
```

or

```
tables = root.cssselect('h3:contains(Impact) ~ table')
```

### Complete solution

```
root = tree.getroot()
tables = root.xpath('.//h3[text()="Impact"]/following-sibling::table')
for table in tables:
    print str
```

Comment: :thank you for your reply
but I still don't know how to save table in a string!

Comment: @NiloofarKhalilian, `lxml.html.tostring(root)` will give you html tring.

Comment: I need this string 
str=<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" class="wrapper-table"><tr> <td><p>An     unauthenticated attacker using a specifically crafted payload may be able to trick the Ruby on Rails backend into executing arbitrary code.</p></td></tr></table>
how can I get this result?

Comment: @NiloofarKhalilian, Did you read my comment? :(

Comment: yes I read it but I'm very new in python.here is my code:
root=tree.getroot()
tables = root.xpath('.//h3[text()="Impact"]/following-sibling::table')
str=etree.tostring(tables)
print str
but I get this error:Type 'list' cannot be serialized

Comment: @NiloofarKhalilian, I added a code.

Comment: I'm realy sorry. I still get this error:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/niloofar/PycharmProjects/Vulnerabillity/Bugtrag/alaki.py", line 24, in <module>
    for table in etree.tostring(tables):
  File "lxml.etree.pyx", line 3127, in lxml.etree.tostring (src\lxml\lxml.etree.c:64508)
TypeError: Type 'list' cannot be serialized.

Comment: @NiloofarKhalilian, I updated the code again. Check it out.